# How to cover for loop with wrapper class in test method?

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, failing-tests, test-setup

I am not getting coverage from " for (FileInfoWrapper file : caseInfo.files)"

```
 @AuraEnabled
public static String loadData(String strCaseInfo) {
    System.debug('caseInfo ' + strCaseInfo);
    CaseInfoWrapper caseInfo = (CaseInfoWrapper)JSON.deserialize(strCaseInfo, CaseInfoWrapper.class);
    
    rand_App_Customer__c customer = getCustomerInfo2(caseInfo.emailId);
    Case cse = new Case();
    cse.subject = 'tan One Problem Report';
    cse.Origin = rand_APP;
    cse.Status = 'Awaiting Approval';
    cse.Priority = 'Medium';
    cse.RecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get(rand_APP).getRecordTypeId();
   
    cse.Description = caseInfo.description;
   
    cse.rand_App_Customer__c = customer?.Id;
    
    cse.Issue_category__c = caseInfo.category;
    cse.Issue_Sub_Category__c = caseInfo.subCategory;
    insert cse;
    // for skip the triggers of ContentDocumentLink && ContentDocument
    ContentDocumentLinkTriggerUtil.skipTrigger = true;
    ContentDocumentTriggerUtil.skipTrigger = true;
    List<ContentVersion> cVersions = new List<ContentVersion>();
    for (FileInfoWrapper file : caseInfo.files) {
        System.debug('fileInfo ' + file);
        if (String.isNotBlank(file.base64Data)) {
            ContentVersion cv = new ContentVersion();
            cv.ContentLocation = 'S';
            cv.PathOnClient = file.fileName;
            cv.VersionData = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(file.base64Data);
            cv.Title = file.fileName;
            cVersions.add(cv);
        }
    }
    List<Id> contentDocumentIds = new List<Id>(caseInfo.contentDocumentIds);
    if (cVersions.size() > 0) {
        insert cVersions;
        List<ContentDistribution> ContentDistributionList = new List<ContentDistribution>();
        for(ContentVersion ctv : cVersions){
            ContentDistribution cd = new ContentDistribution();
            cd.Name = ctv.Title;
            cd.ContentVersionId = ctv.Id;
            cd.PreferencesAllowViewInBrowser = true;
            cd.PreferencesLinkLatestVersion = true;
            cd.PreferencesNotifyOnVisit = false;
            cd.PreferencesPasswordRequired = false;
            cd.PreferencesAllowOriginalDownload = true;
            ContentDistributionList.add(cd);
        }
        if(ContentDistributionList.size() > 0){
            INSERT ContentDistributionList;
        }
        Set<Id> cvIds = new Map<Id, ContentVersion>(cVersions).keySet();
        for (ContentVersion cVersion : [SELECT Id, ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion WHERE Id IN:cvIds ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC]) {
            contentDocumentIds.add(cVersion.ContentDocumentId);
        }
    }
    List<ContentDocumentLink> links = new List<ContentDocumentLink>();
    for (Id contentDocumentId : contentDocumentIds) {
        ContentDocumentLink link = new ContentDocumentLink();
        link.LinkedEntityId = cse.Id;
        link.ContentDocumentId = contentDocumentId;
        link.ShareType = 'V';
        links.add(link);
    }
    insert links;
    return [SELECT CaseNumber FROM Case WHERE Id = :cse.Id]?.CaseNumber;
}
```

this is the wrapper class-

```
public class CaseInfoWrapper {
    @AuraEnabled
    public List<FileInfoWrapper> files { get; set; }

    @AuraEnabled
    public String description { get; set; }

    @AuraEnabled
    public String category { get; set; }

    @AuraEnabled
    public String subCategory { get; set; }

    @AuraEnabled
    public Decimal latitude { get; set; }

    @AuraEnabled
    public Decimal longitude { get; set; }

    @AuraEnabled
    public String locationName { get; set; }

    @AuraEnabled
    public List<Id> contentDocumentIds { get; set; }

    @AuraEnabled
    public String partyId { get; set; }

    @AuraEnabled
    public String mobile { get; set; }

    @AuraEnabled
    public String emailid { get; set; }

    @AuraEnabled
    public String empid { get; set; }

    @AuraEnabled
    public Id randcustomerstart { get; set; }

}
```

This is my test method -

```
@isTest
public static void loadDataTest(){


    rand_App_Customer__c customer = new rand_App_Customer__c();
    customer.Customer_ID__c = '1234567';
    customer.Customer_Email__c = 'tannow@tan.ae';
    insert customer;

    Case caseInfo = new Case();

    caseInfo.subject = 'tan One Problem Report';
    caseInfo.Status = 'Awaiting Approval';
    caseInfo.Priority = 'Medium';
    // cse.RecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get(rand_APP).getRecordTypeId();
    caseInfo.description = 'test';
    caseInfo.RecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('rand_App').getRecordTypeId();
    insert caseInfo;

    ContentVersion contentVersion = new ContentVersion(
    Title = 'Penguins',
    PathOnClient = 'Penguins.jpg',
    VersionData = Blob.valueOf('Test Content'),
    IsMajorVersion = true,
    ContentLocation = 'S'
    );
    insert contentVersion;    
    List<ContentDocument> documents = [SELECT Id, Title, LatestPublishedVersionId FROM ContentDocument];

    //create ContentDocumentLink  record 
    ContentDocumentLink cdl = New ContentDocumentLink();
    cdl.LinkedEntityId = caseInfo.id;
    cdl.ContentDocumentId = documents[0].Id;
    cdl.shareType = 'V';
    insert cdl;

    ContentDistribution cd = new ContentDistribution();
    cd.Name = 'Test';
    cd.ContentVersionId = contentVersion.id;
    cd.PreferencesAllowViewInBrowser= true;
    cd.PreferencesLinkLatestVersion=true;
    cd.PreferencesNotifyOnVisit=false;
    cd.PreferencesPasswordRequired=false;
    cd.PreferencesAllowOriginalDownload= true;
    insert cd;

    String jsoninput = '{"category":"fountain show","subCategory":"fountain","mobile":"1234567890","emailid":"test@gmail.com", "partyId":"12133", "fileName":"test", "base64Data":"test123", "publicUrl":"www.google.com", "contentVersionId":"contentVersion.id", "contentDistributionId": "contentVersion.id" }';
    string str = randAppController.loadData(jsoninput);

     
    Test.startTest();
    try
   {
     randAppController.loadData(str);
   }
   catch(exception e)
     {
    }     
     Test.stopTest();
 }
```

I am getting System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object- on that particular for loop line that I have mentioned above.

Comment: It'd help if you shared the `CaseInfoWrapper` class as well, but the core of the issue here is that you're trying to use `files`, but your `jsoninput` in your test method doesn't include any data for that variable (which is presumably a `List` of nested JSON objects).

Comment: Also, you really should get rid of that try/catch in your test method. Swallowing exceptions doesn't solve the underlying issue, and makes it harder to know what issues you're running into. In tests, you want to know about _every_ failure that happens (so you know that there's a problem and so that you can try to fix it). Also also, making assertions is the most important part of a unit test. You should have multiple tests, and each test should have at least one meaningful assertion.

Comment: Thanks, i have added wrapper class